# Why am I getting an error when using the stripe API?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

I get an error which I have never seen when trying to retrieve the customers stripe information. The error `type: "invalid_request_error"` `message: "This action requires additional privileges"`

```
Cloud Code

var Stripe = require('stripe');
Stripe.initialize('sk_test_xxxxxxxx');
Parse.Cloud.define("Test", function(request, response){
Stripe.Customers.retrieve(request.params.customerId).then(function(results) {
 response.success(results.sources)
},
function(error){
response.error(error);
   });
});
```

ios code

```
if let stripecustomer = object["StripeCustomer"] as? String{
            print("stripec \(stripecustomer)")
            PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("Test", withParameters: ["customerId" : stripecustomer]) { (success: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if(error == nil){
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to call `stripe.customers.retrieve` by curl (https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#customers)? Such that we can isolate if it is a stripe backend issue or otherwise